# Permissioning and SignOn in Java

Tags: java, database, permissions

i'm writing an application in Java, and i would manage the user's permissions (no auth with domain). In other words, an user can see only what has been granted by the admin (Role Based Access Control). I want to know if exist already a framework or something like to manage all directly.

thanks in advance!

Comment: is it a web application? Apache Shiro ( http://shiro.apache.org/ ) is a good candidate.

Comment: no...its a desktop application

Comment: @ArunPJohny, apache shiro can be applied for java desktop applications? I never worked with this framework :(

Comment: I've never worked on desktop applications, so no idea...